# Array order by reputation | Active Record Reputation Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to order a big array by reputation using the ActiveRecordReputation gem.

Is it possible?

I have a model call Microposts, It has a reputation system called :votes.

Those microposts belongs to other model call Group and a User have many groups.

I need to get all the microposts of the groups that the User is suscribe and order it by reputation.

I get a big array of microposts like this:

```
  @microposts = Micropost.joins(:group => :users).where(:users => {id: current_user.id})
```

But it stil missing the reputation order.

I hope you can help me!

Comment: `@microposts.sortby! {|mp| mp.reputation_for(:votes)}` ?

Comment: It sends an error message: undefined method `sortby!' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f84a44396c8>

Comment: Ah, sorry. Then try: `@microposts.sort! {|mp1, mp2| mp1.reputation_for(:votes) <=> mp2.reputation_for(:votes)}`

Comment: This make it work! @microposts.sort! {|mp1, mp2| mp2.reputation(mp2)<=> mp1.reputation(mp1) }

Comment: Hey man! I have another question, how can I get last day records and order it by reputation :o, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`@microposts.sort! {|mp1, mp2| mp1.reputation_for(:votes) <=> mp2.reputation_for(:votes)}` or, if you want the reverse order, then swap mp1 and mp2 in the comparison.